# uniform continuity on disjoint intervals

Tags: uniform-continuity

Consider the following statements

(a) If $f$ is uniformly continuous on disjoint closed intervals $I1,I2,......,In$, then $f$ is
uniformly continuous on $\cup_{j=1}^n Ij$

(b) If $f$ is uniformly continuous on disjoint open intervals $I1,I2,......,In$, then $f$ is
uniformly continuous on $\cup_{j=1}^n Ij$

Which of the following is true.

(A) Both (a) and (b) are correct.

(B) Both (a) and (b) are incorrect.

(C) Only (a) is correct.

(D) Only (b) is correct.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I was thinking if gluing lemma could be helpful. The problem is that it says only about continuity and not uniform continuity.